# How can I right click in Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection while in OS X

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, right-click

I have a MacBook Pro with a touchpad, and the only way I can figure out how to use the right click in my remote desktop session is by plugging in a mouse.

`Ctrl`-click (what I usually use for right click), doesn't work, as `ctrl` is used in Windows for other things. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Try ctrl+shift+click.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Keyboard Shortcuts**

- **CTRL + SHIFT + CLICK:** Right Click (OS X)
- **CTRL + ALT + END :** Opens the Microsoft Widnows NT security dialog box.
- **ALT + PAGEUP :** Switch between programs left to right.
- **ALT + PAGEDOWN :** Switch between programs right to left.
- **ALT + INSERT :** Cycle through programs in most recently used order.
- **ALT + HOME :** Display Start Menu.
- **CTRL + ALT + BREAK :** Switch the client computer between a window and full screen.
- **ALT + DELETE :** Displays the windows menu.
- **CTRL + ALT + Minus Sign (-) :** Place a snapshot of the active window in the client the     terminal server, same as PRINT SCREEN on a local computer.
- **CTRL + ALT + Plus Sign (+) :** Place a snapshot of the entire window in the client the terminal server, same as PRINT SCREEN on a local computer.

Comment: Is there a way to get shift to work so you can input symbols?

Comment: ctrl+shift+click does not work.  Daniel's answer works, double tab

Comment: +1 on "ctrl+shift+click does not work. Daniel's answer works, double tab" - attempting an edit to correct...

Answer (score 15):

Either using two finger tap, or two finger "click" (by pressing down on the touchpad).

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's surely the simplest - for one-handed operation.

Comment: This is the only answer that works for me (pressing down on the touchpad with 2 fingers).  Even 2-finger tap doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

This is kind of embarrassing, but the real problem was I didn't know how to right click with a touchpad on the macbook (it was still less than a month old). Update: You can do this by clicking or tapping with both fingers at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can simulate the RIGHT-CLICK as follows;

use the arrow to position where you wish to right-click
then use the keyboard icon and select SHIFT and F10

When you tap the keyboard pad to disappear you hopefully will have the right-click menu you want.

Comment: This works for me in *some* Windows apps, but not others.